# How would I deserialize some class from XML (file), and vice versa?

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, linq-to-xml, xelement, xml-deserialization

I have the following class and data members (plus irrelevant methods) I am new to XML and .NET (that excuse is getting old though) and have spent a couple of days reading the MSDN entries (and whatever google turned up) for first XMLReader, then XMLDocument and now XDocument, XElement and XNode but am no closer to a concrete solution to serializing my class (perhaps I need to study serialization in .NET in more depth). To get me started I have some data in an XML file that I want to read (although it prolly is in the wrong format) in to initialize a class to initialize my application. The configuration class is as follows:

```
class IWantToFile
{
    class DirsAndFiles
    {
        public List<string> Suffixes;
        public string Dir;
    }
    enum OPOptsEnum
    {
        op1Description, op2Description, op3Description, op4Description,
        op5Description, op6Description, op7Description, op8Description,
    };
    List<DirsAndFiles> ProjectDirs;
    bool[] OPOpts = new bool[(int)OPOptsEnum.op8Description + 1];
    bool otherOpt;
}
```

Observing the one to one and one to many relationships therein (eg `List<DirsAndFiles> ProjectDirs`) can someone please give concise methods to read and write this data to a file? It would greatly assist my development in these fields.

I've got as far as:

```
        if (File.Exists(SPECFILENAME)) {
            XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(SPECFILENAME);
            //Ummm.....
        }
```

but then my lack of .NET XML and Linq exeperience fail me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you might want to use the [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx), which 'Serializes and deserializes objects into and from XML documents'?

See [How to serialize an object to XML by using Visual C#](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815813) for sample code.

Comment: I'm sure I tried reading that microsoft howto earlier and it was in VB, maybe it was this, http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316730/en-us. I'd just set my SDK's MDE to XMLserializer, but what a lot of code?! So I need to be using that before studying XDocument, XElement and XName? Perhaps starting with serializing my data would assist in writing the deserialize code...

Comment: would writing a XML Schema and using xsd.exe generate a serializable class for me?

Answer (score 1):

```
[Serializable]
public class MyObject
{
    public string SerializeMe { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public string DONTSerializeMe { get; set; }
}
```

Helper....

```
public static class SerializerHelper<T>
{
    public static string Serialize(T myobject)
    {
        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        xmlSerializer.Serialize(stringWriter, myobject);
        string xml = stringWriter.ToString();

        return xml;
    }
    public static T Deserialize(string xml)
    {
        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(xml);
        return (T)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(stringReader);
    }
}
```

Usage

```
MyObject myObject = new MyObject();
string xml = SerializerHelper<MyObject>.Serialize(myObject);
MyObject DeserializedObject = SerializerHelper<MyObject>.Deserialize(xml);
```

Comment: You are creating an object of type MyObject but then serializing as type MyClass!  I don't think this will work.  Typo?

Comment: thanks, yes. Oh the evils of not copying and pasting! Who would have said that lol.

Comment: lol.  Yeah, copying a pasting can bring its own evils if you're not careful!